# How to add the feet and inches to the decimal before and after code?

Tags: php

I'm using the code below to convert meters to feet. It works like a charm but I would like to add inches part after the decimal point.

**Present output**

```
6.2 feet
```

**Desired output**

```
6 feet 2 inches
```

or

```
6'2"
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$meters=$dis[height];
$inches_per_meter = 39.3700787;
$inches_total = round($meters * $inches_per_meter); /* round to integer */
$feet = $inches_total / 12 ; /* assumes division truncates result; if not use floor() */
$inches = $inches_total % 12; /* modulus */
echo "(". round($feet,1) .")"; 
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number after the decimal point is *not* inches, as there's 12 inches in a foot. What you want to do is convert centimetres to inches, and then convert inches to feet and inches. I do it as follows:

```
<?php

// this is the value you want to convert
$centimetres = $_POST['height']; // 180

// convert centimetres to inches
$inches = round($centimetres/2.54);

// now find the number of feet...
$feet = floor($inches/12);

// ..and then inches
$inches = ($inches%12);

// you now have feet and inches, and can display it however you wish
printf('You are %d feet %d inches tall', $feet, $inches);
```